# Trouble with translating a phrase in Wuxia fiction (萬里追風身法)

Tags: translation

I have come across the following phrase in a novel that I am reading, and I cannot figure out if this is someone's moniker or a martial arts move: 萬里追風身法. Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: The author doesn't seem to be a native Chinese speaker. The names he came up with for Martial Arts novel terms are quite unnatural to Chinese ears

Answer (score 2):

萬里追風身法

It is a fictional Chinese martial arts "technique", (身法); and the idea being that a trained martial arts exponent could run so fast that he could even "chase the wind", (追風), for thousands of 里, (萬里), which, I suppose, is equivalent to “...faster than a speeding bullet”, which is used to describe the Western comic book character "Superman".

Another Chinese martial arts technique, which sounds super human, is the "shadowless kick" (無影腳); the kicking leg moving so fast that it casts no shadow at all.

Answer (score 1):

萬里 (thousands of miles) = ultra-long distance

追風 (chasing wind) = high speed moving

身法 (body maneuver skill) = ability

Word-for-word translation would be too wordy in English. You can descriptively call it: "hyper-speed mode" or dramatically call it: "hurricane move"